# IIS website only allowing https connection, no http

Tags: http, iis, https, windows-server-2012, port-number

(I tried asking this on the webmasters stack but it said I could only post once every 40 mins despite never posting on there before....)

I  am running two websites on IIS (site1.site.com and site2.site.com).

Both sites have the same bindings but with different host names (as above), on IP address * and for Ports 80 and 443 (http and https respectively).

site1 is externally accessible via both protocols, however site2 will only work via https. Curiously, if I go to SSL Settings the 'Require SSL' box is unchecked and Client certificates set to 'Ignore'.

What do I change to allow site2 to be accessible via http (secure connection is actually not required at all)

Comment: What exactly happens when you use `http://site2.site.com` in the browser? Page cannot be found?

Comment: This site can't be reached with the error code ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: Can you use the Developer Tools of your web browser to analyze the HTTP request message when http://site2.site.com is navigated to? Check if its destination IP address and Host header matches. Then on your IIS server, check if the request arrives (using a tool such as Wireshark).